# Mapping SQL query behind a button click(oracle apex)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a GUI for my data base . I have uploaded my data on apex.oracle , i can apply queries and get the data i want .What i want next is to create GUI with buttons and a display form so that when user  clicks the button a sql query executes in the back end and result is showed in the display form.Is there any tutorial online for that?

Any help would be appreciated

Update
I read the manual . I have watched many youtube tutorials but my GUI is different .I thing i need to change my view to "Component view".But i cant find the icon
here is sreen shot from manual
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjIAv.png)

and below is my GUI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVL1I.png)

Basically when i create a new form on the same page .But when i click on "+"(in region tab) my page automatically adds it as a "static content".
As in the video below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nm5sVJpeZ8c
i want  a new window to pop when creating button ,text field,form on the same page.But my app automatically adds it and i have to change attributes after the addition.
I just want a simple search form as shown in the video

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an Apex manual?

This one is "Application Express Application Builder User's Guide"

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/HTMDB/toc.htm

Bobby